# Angular ngAnimate, how to mix transitions?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

In single page Application with `ngAnimate` defined:

```
var app= angular.module("demoApp", ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);
```

Is it possible to set some routing pages with x transitions and others with y transitions?

I would like to mix transitions up.

**Update 1**

This proposal:

```
 $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        var newPath = next.$$route.originalPath;
        ...
        $("#elementID").removeClass('view-animate');
    });
```

I tried this but it did not work. The same transition always triggered regardless of whatever I made to the element even removing the class as I did in the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically it should be possible. What you would have to do is to change the class of the container when routing starts. You could write your own directive for that. The code would be something like

```
scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    var newPath = next.$$route.originalPath;
    // determine the class based on the path
    // set the class on the ng-view div
    // or toggle one class if you need only two different transitions
    element.toggleClass(transitionClass);
```

In your css you can define different transitions for those classes. One thing to keep in mind that this would affect both the enter and the leave animation at once.